# C# - custom triangle class, call for values

Tags: c#, class, call

I'm trying to create a custom class to hold three vertex positions that define a triangle to draw and subdivide.  The problem I'm running into is how to make sure I return the correct values.

here's the code that I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Icosahedron_Test
{
    class TriXYZ
    {
        Vector3 vertex1;
        Vector3 vertex2;
        Vector3 vertex3;
        int depth;
        float material; // float because the material can be part grass / part dirt or part sand / part rock, etc...  for blending

        public TriXYZ(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2, Vector3 pos3, int tDepth)
        {
            vertex1 = pos1;
            vertex2 = pos2;
            vertex3 = pos3;
            depth = tDepth;
        }

        public TriXYZ(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2, Vector3 pos3, int tDepth, float tMaterial)
        {
            vertex1 = pos1;
            vertex2 = pos2;
            vertex3 = pos3;
            depth = tDepth;
            material = tMaterial;
        }

        public Vector3 Vertex1(TriXYZ triangle)
        {
            return vertex1;
        }
        public Vector3 Vertex2(TriXYZ triangle)
        {
            return vertex2;
        }
        public Vector3 Vertex3(TriXYZ triangle)
        {
           return vertex3;
        }
        public int Depth(TriXYZ triangle)
        {
            return depth;
        }
        public Vector3 Midpoint(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2, int tDepth)
        {
            Vector3 midpoint;  // returned midpoint between the two inputted vectors

            //PLACEHOLDER

            return midpoint;
        }

    }
}
```

I create a new Triangle element like this:

```
new TriXYZ(pos1, pos2, pos3, depth); // the depth will deal with LOD later on
```

so, in order to get the value for the vertex positions, I'm calling the class like this:

```
vertex1 = TriXYZ.Vertex1(verticiesList[listPos]);
```

My issue is that I'm not sure if it's working, and I'm not entirely sure how to check it at this point, because there's not enough here to actually make the program run.  Does the theory behind this seem like it would work?

Also, as a side note, I'm an amateur programmer, so if there are any glaring issues with this that are going against coding standards, feel free to point them out to me ^^

Comment: This is a good time to write unit tests

Comment: interesting, I'd missed that before.  Thank you for pointing that out to me, I'll be sure to do that.   And I'll have to look up what unit tests are.....

Comment: @Patrick Reynolds: Just google unit testing in .net or look for tutorials with NUnit... that should get you started. Lots of examples out there.

Comment: much obliged, but will .net work with c# and XNA?

Comment: Warning: Quick and probably inadequate (or incorrect) explanation: .Net is a framework that includes a common language runtime (CLR), which provides a layer of abstraction over the operating system (it also includes some base class libraries etc.). C# is a language that is compiled into an intermediate language, which is then executed by the CLR. XNA is a framework based on the .Net framework (not sure if it is just a customized version optimized for games...). So I would guess that you can just unit test in a similar fashion. To be safe, I'd check this site: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.. mostly... as much sense as it can to an amateur.  Thanks for the responses.

Comment: It'll become more clear the more you work with it. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want are getters for those vertex variables.

This is because you should not try to make those functions static (from the way you're trying to call them), do the following instead:

```
public Vector3 Vertex1()
{
    return vertex1;
}
public Vector3 Vertex2()
{
    return vertex2;
}
public Vector3 Vertex3()
{
    return vertex3;
}
```

If what you really want are getters, then I'd recommend getting a more explicit name like `GetVertex1`, or even better, put it as a **property** like so:

```
public Vector3 Vertex1 { get; private set; }
```

So, what exactly is a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)? It's just a nicer way to get or set data.

Here, we specify `public` to be the access level of the vertex, so that `Vertex1` can be **accessed** publicly (you can **get** the value of the vertex outside of the class). Like so:

```
Vector3 vertex = triangle.Vertex1;
```

In this particular situation, you may or may not want other people from outside of the class to **change** the vertex. If you don't want them to change it, you specify the **setter** of the property to be `private`, so that you can only change `Vertex1`'s value within the class.

You'd use it this way:

```
TriXYZ myTriangle = new TriXYZ(pos1, pos2, pos3, depth);
Vector3 vertex1 = myTriangle.Vertex1;
```

Comment: so, if I'm drawing from a list of triangles, then I need to assign the value in the list to a variable, then do: variable.Vertex1(); and that will return my value?

Comment: If you want to access the position of a vertex from a triangle (from a list or whatever), you'd just do `triangle.Vertex1` to access it (if you are using properties like I suggested in my new edit).

Comment: could you explain this to me: public Vector3 Vertex1 { get; private set; }
    Like I said, I'm new at this, and this confuses me a bit.  I've seen it a couple of times in the books I have, but I've never come across an actual explanation of what this is or what it does.

Comment: Oh sure! Give me a couple of minutes to edit my post to give a better explanation than with comments.

Comment: Edited. Added a link that probably explains it better than I do. I just showed the way I understand them, but feel free to search for more in depth tutorials about properties, they're pretty awesome imo.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I just don't understand.  what is the "get" doing?  I'm not seeing a variable associated with it, so I don't understand how it's returning my vertex position.  is there a { return Vector3 } after this?   sorry for all the trouble.  I'll look at that link as well (had laready posted this before I saw that XD)

Comment: You used to need to keep a variable like `Vector3 m_vertex1` and do `get { return m_vertex1; }` and `set { m_vertex1 = value; }`. But with C# 3.0(I believe), you can just do `Vector3 Vertex1 { get; set; }` and the annoying job of keeping a separate variable is done for you.

Comment: thank you so much for the help and the link.  I should be able to figure it out from here ^^  Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [this C# Source file](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidA8AC0A8D7985146AABEB95C8F675352DB5F9EA87.aspx?s=%22Jan+Varwig%22). It is doing essentially what your trying to do.

Comment: Hm, interesting.  Thanks for that link, it has a lot of what I'm looking to do.  what does this mean: #region Properties, does it define a portion of code, or is it just for documenting?

Comment: @Patrick -- No, what it does is, if you are using Visual Studio, it creates a collapsable region of code. You can ignore it. Its just to make the code look better in Visual Studio

Comment: ah, useful.  I'll keep that in mind since I'm using visual studio ^^